# Ordem dos posts quando consulto a base de dados do meu CMS

Tags: php, mysql, cms, classificação

Estou a desenvolver um Site com CMS. Funciona tudo perfeitamente só que gostaria que os últimos posts estivessem no topo da página. O que está a acontecer agora é que os últimos posts vão para o fim da página só queria que a ordem fosse oposta.

#### PHP Class "Article"

```
<?php
class Article {
  public function fetch_all() {
    global $pdo;

    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles");
    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetchAll();
  }

  public function fetch_data($article_id) {
    global $pdo;

    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id=?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $article_id);
    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetch();
  }
}
?>
```

#### index.php

```
<?php
include_once('includes/connection.php');
include_once('includes/article.php');

$article = new Article;
$articles = $article->fetch_all();
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CMS Tutorial</title>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="index.php" id ="logo">CMS</a>
    <ol>
      <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>
      <li>
      <?php echo $article['article_title']; ?>
        - <small>
            posted <?php echo date('l jS', $article['article_timestamp']); ?>
          </small>
      </li>
      <p><?php echo $article['article_content']; ?></p>
      <?php }?>         
    </ol>
    <br>
    <small><a href="admin">admin</a></small>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você quer ordenado por data ou pelo id de inserção?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que deu para entender da tua pergunta e com base nos comentários que já deixaste nas respostas existentes, a tua tabela `articles` contém um campo com o nome `article_timestamp`.

Assumindo que o campo efectivamente contém dados do tipo *Unix timestamp*, um `datetime` ou `date`, e que o valor guardado diz respeito à data do teu registo, podes realizar a consulta da seguinte forma:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY article_timestamp DESC");
/*                      └──┬───┘ └─────┬─────┘ └──────────────┬──────────────┘     */
/*                         ↓           ↓                      ↓                    */
/*                    Seleccionar   da tabela         ordenado pelo campo          */
/*                       tudo       articles      article_timestamp de forma       */
/*                                                       descendente               */
```

Onde estás a dizer que pretendes recolher tudo da tabela `articles` mas ordenado pelo campo `article_timestamp` de forma descendente.

---

## Não relacionado

Não relacionado com o problema em questão, mas reparei que na *markup* de HTML na tua pergunta, tens um `<p></p>` fora de contexto, ou seja, após fechares a `li` mas antes de fechares a `ol` estás a aplicar um paragrafo.

Tal situação não é permitida, deverás colocar o paragrafo dentro da `li`, antes do fecho da mesma:

```
<ol>
  <?php
  foreach ($articles as $article) {
    echo '
    <li>
      '.$article["article_title"].'
      - <small> posted '.date("l jS", $article["article_timestamp"]).'</small>
      <p>'.$article["article_content"].'</p>
    </li>';
  }
  ?>         
</ol>
```

<sup>Da forma que tens. apesar de funcionar bem em alguns navegadores por os mesmos *ignorarem esse lapso*, não funciona bem em todos, particularmente nos mais antigos.</sup>

Comment: Exatamente, pela 3ª-4ª vez ajudaste-me e de maneira concisa e muito acessível, apesar de eu me ter explicado mal (faltou  esclarecer por que ordem eu queria que fosse postado, mas era mesmo pela data Obgado

Comment: Já emendei muito obgado

Comment: Já agora zuul, como posso a date em português? em que parte? dsculpa pelo incomodo

Comment: @Miguel Não é incomodo nenhum, mas é _off-topic_ nesta pergunta :) O ideal será colocares uma nova pergunta sobre a apresentação de uma data por extenso em português via PHP. Dás o exemplo da data que tens e como esperas que ela fique em Português. Rapidamente terás a solução :)

Comment: ok vou tratar disso obgado, tens razão...

Answer (score 3):

Você está usando qual CMS. De como você está mostrando. A sua query deve estar assim, se você estiver usando o PHP PDO:

```
public function fetch_all() {
  $sql  = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
  $stmt = Connection::prepare( $sql );
  $stmt->execute();

  return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Adicione na sua SQL a seguinte parte para ele pegar os em ordem decrescente.

```
public function fetch_all() {
  $sql  = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY article_id DESC";
  $stmt = Connection::prepare( $sql );
  $stmt->execute();

  return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: Editei em cima o codigo tentei acrescentar o "ORDER BY...." ao '$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles");' mas desapareceu tudo

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca Sem ofensa, mas a edição não resolveu o problema nesta resposta. A consulta apresentada na função `fetch_all` não corresponde à da pergunta na mesma função. Além disso, a consulta nesta resposta não funciona por espera um parâmetro para o `article_id`, que por si já é errado pois estamos a dizer que só queremos um registo, onde como o nome da própria função o indica, a ideia é puxar tudo.

Comment: Editaram isso Zull. Não foi eu que fiz. Quando eu escrevi, ela buscava todos os dados de forma decrescente.

Comment: Arrumado Zuul. :)

Comment: @RandsonJarthis Zuul not Zull :)

Answer (score 0):

Adicione ORDER BY "id" DESC por exemplo, à sua query SQL que pega os POSTS do banco de dados.

Comment: Eu sou muito novato, '$query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO articles(article_title, article_content, article_timestamp) VAlUES (?, ?, ?)')' Adiciono a isto?

Comment: Esse parece ser o codigo que insere na base de dados, não o que vai buscar... Não é no ficheiro index.php que pus em cima?

Comment: Adcionei a classe que vai buscar os dados à base... tentei implementar ali o que me disse, mas não está resultando, está a desaparecer